# ¿Como reiniciar el proceso de una aplicación windows forms en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, signalr

Tengo una aplicación windows forms que le he generado el instalador (con clickonce), que si la ejecuto nuevamente, termino el proceso de la aplicación actual para que vuelva a iniciar. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 public Form1()
    {          
            int i = 1;
            foreach (Process proceso in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (proceso.ProcessName == "AplicacionWinForms")
                {
                    if (i > 1)
                    {
                        proceso.Kill();
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;

                }
            }
            InitializeComponent();
            //Resto de codigo para comunicarse con otra aplicación con signalR
            IncializaSignalR();
            hubConnection.Closed += IncializaSignalR;
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
   }

  //aunque esta función no es relevante, pero igual la incluyo por siacaso
  private void IncializaSignalR()
    {
            hubConnection = new HubConnection("www.paginaservidor.cl/signalr/hubs");
            hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub4");
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
   //bla bla bla...resto de codigo

}
```

La aplicación se comunica con otra otra mediante signalR, cuando coloco el computador en suspensión, y después vuelvo a encenderlo, me doy cuenta que pierde la conexión, por lo que debo finalizar el proceso y volverlo a iniciarlo, y de esa forma, se vuelve a conectar.

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de reiniciar el proceso de la aplicación cuando vuelva a entrar, o que por lo menos que cuando haga click al ejecutuble, reinicie la aplicación, sin la necesidad de finalizar el proceso y volverlo a ejecutar para restablecer la conexión.
Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: A ver si entendi. Tu aplicacion se queda abierta en background aunque aparentemente se la cierran?

Comment: Al revisar en el administrador de tareas de windows, despues de volver a entrar a windows en donde antes estaba en estado de suspensión el equipo, veo que está en ejecución. Trato de hacer uso de la aplicación escritorio, y veo que no hace nada, entonces finalizo tarea, y vuelvo a ejecutarlo, y ahí si vuelve a funcionar. Lo que deseo es evitar este paso de finalizar e iniciar tarea para que se vuelva a conectar con la otra aplicación en signalR. Que de alguna forma el código lo haga solo.

Comment: Tuve una situación parecida y me funciono utilizando `Application.Current.Shutdown();` pero era una aplicacion WPF. Intentalo y dime si te funciono.

Comment: Creo que con esto se hace:
  Application.Restart();, pero me gustaría saber si existe alguna configuración desde el mismo código o en windows, que al entrar la session,se ejecute sola la aplicación.

Comment: Te refieres a [esto](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240791/how-to-run-programs-automatically-when-a-user-logs-on)?

Comment: @Pikoh si, pero que en el codigo se encargue de hacer ese registro. En este caso, tengo un ejemplo que se ejecuta la aplicación al encender o reiniciar el computador:
       RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
string startPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)
                                   + @"\AppEscritorio\AppEscritorio\AppEscritorio.appref-ms";                rkApp.SetValue("AppEscritorio", startPath);
Pero en este caso, para el inicio de sessión necesito

Comment: El problema es que para hacer ese cambio, la aplicacion debe tener los permisos suficientes para cambiar politicas de grupo. No se si eso es viable en tu caso

Comment: [aqui tienes una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316511/579895) sobre como editar politicas de grupo desde c#

Comment: @Pikoh, donde llego a esa configuracion que indicaste:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240791/how-to-run-programs-automatically-when-a-user-logs-on

Comment: @Pikoh,  y como lo agrego?:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240791/how-to-run-programs-automatically-when-a-user-logs-on

Comment: Yo nunca lo hice, pero debes combinar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316511/579895) con la informacion de [microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240791/how-to-run-programs-automatically-when-a-user-logs-on)

Answer (score 1):

Qué tal si controlas por tiempos? Podrías hacer que cada minuto compruebe si hay conexión con tu otra app y sí falla la conexión que mande a reiniciar tu app, de esta forma.

```
public void EventTimer(int tiempoSegundos, EventHandler evento)
{
    Timer aTimer = new Timer();
    aTimer.Interval = tiempoSegundos * 1000;
    aTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(evento);
    aTimer.Start();
}
EventTimer(60, HideForm);
private void HideForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Intentas comprobar la conexión con tu otra aplicación
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        //Application.ExitThread(); Esto es para abandonar los hilos que emplees, te lo dejo porque sospecho que lo necesitarás
        Application.Restart();
    }
}
```