# ¿Cómo ejecutar un programa o aplicación al iniciar sesión en windows de forma automatica?

Tags: windows, registro-windows, configuración

Me gustaría saber, que cuando inicio sesión en windows, despues que haya puesto en suspensión el computador,pudiera ejecutarse un programa automaticamente.

Quisiera saber donde y como debería configurar para que esto sea posible(quizas en el regedit, o algo en directiva de grupos, ¿pero como?). espero sus aportes por favor, ya que me es muy importante.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como reiniciar el proceso de una aplicación windows forms en C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131665/como-reiniciar-el-proceso-de-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-windows-forms-en-c)

Comment: Esta pregunta no termina de ajustarse bien a los temas pertinentes al sitio, ya que realmente no trata sobre programación (sería diferente si lo que quisieras hacer es crear un programa que haga lo que buscas).

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta por no ajustarse al [alcance definido para el sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ni parece tratar acerca de otros temas [discutidos por la comunidad](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/127).

Answer (score 2):

Abre el editor de registro desde Ejecturar>regedit y navega a la ruta

```
Equipo\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Crea un valor cadena donde pongas la ruta absoluta de tu archivo EXE

[image: Editor de registro]

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, tendrías que tratar de ser un poco más detallista en cuanto explicar tu situación... Si mal no entendí, quieres hacer que, un programa, se ejecute ni bien "inicia" **Windows**.

Para hacer esto, tienes que poner el ejecutable dentro de la carpeta alojada **(en la gran parte de los casos)** en **esta ruta**: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

Comment: gracias por responder, pero no me resulto, la ruta que me diste esta correcta, pero no se ejecuta el programa.
Lo que deseo, es que cuando dejo el computador en suspensión, después vuelvo a entrar a windows, se ejecute un programa, por ejemplo que se abra un block de notas.

Comment: Ok! Espero que puedas solucionarlo pronto... seguiré buscando alguna solución :^D

Comment: resulta solamente cuando reinicio windows, pero cuando bloqueo el equipo, o cierro sesión y vuelvo a aparecer, no funciona

Comment: Hola Mathias, evita usar saludos y firmas en tus publicaciones. Puedes encontrar más información en [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Un saludo.

Comment: Ok! Lo tendré en cuenta :D